# didRangeBeacons not getting uuid in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I used the following code to get message from a particular beacon but it always shows null in uuid. When i run this code the "viewdidLoad method works fine but when it comes to didRangebeacons it shows only the last uuid beacons. Actually i want to check that Is beacon available for particular uuid and receive that signals and keep on checking for uuids in array and when it receives another signal it should display that beacon signal also.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

NSLog(@"Before assigning UUID");


NSArray *uuidArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"9146947B-441D-4116-B60E-4DD4659825AB", @"9146947B-441D-4116-B60E-4DD46598257C", @"9146947B-441D-4116-B60E-4DD46598257B", nil];


for(int i=0; i<[uuidArr count]; i++)

{

NSString *uuidTemp = [uuidArr objectAtIndex:i];

NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidTemp];


self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:@"com.gimbal.iosexample"];


[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];

[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];

if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) 
{


NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monitoring not available for  %@", uuidTemp];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Monitoring not available" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
[alert show]; return;

}

}


}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{    

NSLog(@"iBeacons found");

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfully found" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
[alert show];


self.statusLabel.text = @"iBeacon found!";


CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;

NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];

NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuid);

}


@end
```

Can anyone help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating different beacon regions in your for loop, but your region identifier is the same, so the second region definition will replace the first, and then the second will be replaced by the third. You need to use a unique region identifier - something like

```
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.gimbal.iosexample.%d",i]];
```